# Android Get Mapview on Fling stopped animating

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I need to limit the area my users can navigate to in the mapview (unless they'll get a blank screen!).
I have created a class that extends the mapview and overridden the onTouchEvent. 
I am detecting the action "ACTION_UP" and checking the coords here and repostioning the map if I have to. Everything works fine until the user "flings" the map. I can detect the "Up" and the coordinates of the screen at that point, but the map is still moving so the coordinates I detect aren't the correct ones.

I need to know the screen position when it's stopped moving!

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
//get coords of screen corners and calculate if the map is still in view.
}
```

I have been looking for a fair amount of time for the answer to this but lots of people are asking the question, but there don't appear to be any solutions around?

Has anyone managed to do this?

Bex

Comment: Yes sadly the standard `GestureDetector` provides information on when a fling starts, but not when it ends. I'll take a look and see if the end of a fling can be detected easily. You could override `onFling` and just disable flinging by returning `false` from there. Also it would be better to check the position of the map when an `ACTION_MOVE` event occurs, rather than the up event or the map will "leap" back to it's position if you moved to far when you lift your finger.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for your comment! If you could see if it's possible to get the end of the fling that would be brilliant! Failing that disabling on fling might be the best option!

Comment: I've added the gesture listener.. but the on fling event doesn't fire?!

Comment: Yes, apologies, after looking at the source it is apparent that MapView uses it's own gesture system and does not implement the `GestureDetector` from the SDK. You might be a little stuck... Edit: you could try the `stopAnimation` and `stopPanning` methods of `MapController` when the user lifts their finger and see if that stops the fling.

Comment: I have managed to stop the fling, I was using the wrong listener! It makes it appear quite clunky!  If could detect the end of the pan it would make things so much easier! :)

Comment: You have to return true from the onFling method: it means that the event has been consumed and it doesn't propagate it to the default listener.

Answer (score 0):

i use to override the computeScroll() method of the MapView:

```
/**
 * checks restriction on pan bounds and locks the map. if the map is locked
 * (via mapController.getCenter()) this method returns true
 * 
 * @return TRUE if map has been locked
 */
private boolean restrictPanOnBounds() {
  if (this.minLatitudeE6 == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
    return false;

  GeoPoint center = getMapCenter();
  int cLat = center.getLatitudeE6();
  int cLong = center.getLongitudeE6();

  Integer nLat = null, nLong = null;

  if (cLat < this.minLatitudeE6)
    nLat = this.minLatitudeE6;
  else if (cLat > this.maxLatitudeE6)
    nLat = this.maxLatitudeE6;

  if (cLong < this.minLongitudeE6)
    nLong = this.minLongitudeE6;
  else if (cLong > this.maxLongitudeE6)
    nLong = this.maxLongitudeE6;

  if (nLat != null || nLong != null) {
    getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(nLat != null ? nLat : cLat, nLong != null ? nLong : cLong));
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

@Override
public void computeScroll() {
  if (restrictPanOnBounds())
    getController().stopPanning();
  else
    super.computeScroll();
}
```

it works quite well for simple move actions ( the map stops has does not jump back ) but still has a "funny" tilt effect when flinging...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Your approach is good, just need to catch the event on another place. You can override "DispatchTouchEvent" method of MapView class (or take similar approach using MapFragment), and there you make it skip MotionEvent.ACTION_UP event:

```
if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
   return false;
}
```