# Disable Mapview scrolling while Zooming android

Tags: java, android, ios, google-maps

is there any option Google Map android Similar to iOS GoogleMap.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom?

basically what i want to achieve is to keep my Relative Layout of Marker in Center of Map.

Comment: Please star this feature request to let Google know that we need it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69795937

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958074/android-googlemaps-v2-disable-scroll-on-pan-or-zoom/32734436#32734436). Although because of `ScaleGestureDetector` bug it will work only API > 16. Use regular `Mapview` with scale gestures enabled on API <= 16 and API > 16. [Reference.](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/940)

```
    public class CustomEventMapView extends MapView {

    private int fingers = 0;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private long lastZoomTime = 0;
    private float lastSpan = -1;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private ScaleGestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public CustomEventMapView(Context context, GoogleMapOptions options) {
        super(context, options);
    }

    public CustomEventMapView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void getMapAsync(final OnMapReadyCallback callback) {
        super.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
                gestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                        if (lastSpan == -1) {
                            lastSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
                        } else if (detector.getEventTime() - lastZoomTime >= 50) {
                            lastZoomTime = detector.getEventTime();
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(getZoomValue(detector.getCurrentSpan(), lastSpan)), 50, null);
                            lastSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                        lastSpan = -1;
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                        lastSpan = -1;

                    }
                });
                CustomEventMapView.this.googleMap = googleMap;
                callback.onMapReady(googleMap);
            }
        });
    }

    private float getZoomValue(float currentSpan, float lastSpan) {
        double value = (Math.log(currentSpan / lastSpan) / Math.log(1.55d));
        return (float) value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                fingers = fingers + 1;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                fingers = fingers - 1;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                fingers = 0;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                fingers = 1;
                break;
        }
        if (fingers > 1) {
            disableScrolling();
        } else if (fingers < 1) {
            enableScrolling();
        }
        if (fingers > 1) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    private void enableScrolling() {
        if (googleMap != null && !googleMap.getUiSettings().isScrollGesturesEnabled()) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
                }
            }, 50);
        }
    }

    private void disableScrolling() {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        if (googleMap != null && googleMap.getUiSettings().isScrollGesturesEnabled()) {
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here's a related thread which might help: [MapView - Disable dragging around, but allow zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186801/mapview-disable-dragging-around-but-allow-zooming)

Comment: Thank you for your reply...

But The App is crashing Using the implementation of mapview provided by you.

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]